# Difference between any books and any book

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "you may borrow any book you like" and "you may borrow any books you like"?

I couldn't find explanations for this question in my country's website, so it is so helpful for me if you could provide the information.

Comment: There is not a rigid difference between the two -- it depends a lot on the context and the formality of speech for those who are speaking.

Comment: Common understanding would be you offered me any one book or many books.

Comment: How many books are you allowed to borrow?

Comment: Can you borrow any number of books, or any one regardless of value/size/rarity?

Answer (score 4):

The literal difference between the two statements is simple. "Book" says that you can borrow any one book; "books" says you can borrow more than one book.

People can and do use "book" when they mean you can borrow more than one. It's context dependant. In other similar sentences it would be clearer. If someone said "You can take any cake you like" they almost certainly meant you could take only one. "Any cakes you like" would certainly mean more than one.

Comment: Note that in your "cake" example, "any cake" could refer to a variety of cake, not a specific cake. E.g. "You can choose any cake you like for your wedding."

Comment: @Barmar True in your example. I deliberately chose "take" to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Yes; 'you may borrow any book you like' is ambiguous. It could be using the prototypical singular or the distributive singular. To specify 'one and one only', 'you may borrow any one book you like' can be used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it would be clear in most contexts, and explicitly saying "any one book" feels redundant.

Comment: @Barmar Anything that pre-empts semantic disputes is far from redundant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are times when precision is needed, and times when it sounds wordy.